# How can I change the recipe to make it Unbreakable?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

The code is right there but basically I want to make it where it makes the diamond sword unbreakable and also with a name.

```
{
    "type": "minecraft:crafting_shaped",
    "pattern": [
        " # ",
        " # ",
        " / "
    ],
    "key": {
        "#": {
            "item": "minecraft:obsidian"
        },
        "/": {
            "item": "minecraft:blaze_rod"
        }
    },
    "result": {
        "item": "minecraft:diamond_sword",
        "count": 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of the current Minecraft update (1.14.4) it is not possible to add custom NBT to crafting recipes, so you will be unable to give it a custom name and enchantments.

Comment: …which means you need to swap it out in the inventory later. How to do that is a bit complicated, I have a broad idea, but haven't programmed it in the game yet. But the basic way is `/clear` and `/give`, that just moves the item into a different slot.

Comment: Can I add damage modifiers at least?

Answer (score 0):

## There is a way!

I was searching for a way to do this and I found a creative solution.

You will need an advancement, recipe, and a function.

- The recipe should *not* be shapeless, and the recipe should give a knowledge book.
- The advancement should look like:

```
{
    "criteria": {
        "Unlocked": {
            "trigger": "minecraft:recipe_unlocked",
            "conditions": {
                "recipe": "RECIPE NAME"
            }
        }
    },
    "rewards": {
        "function": "FUNCTION NAME"
    }
}
```

- And the function should look like:

```
recipe take @s (RECIPE NAME)

advancement revoke @s only (ADVANCEMENT NAME)

(GIVE COMMAND FOR ITEM)

clear @s minecraft:knowledge_book
```

This has been super useful to me in the past, and it's the only way I know where you can use the vanilla crafting table for custom nbt recipes.
*Note: There is no way to require custom nbt crafting materials unless you use a custom crafting table*